# What parts of the regular Linux graphics driver architecture is used in Android?

Tags: kernel, usb-drivers

For example, could the Nouveau driver be used and provide hardware accelerated drawing when Android is compiled for x86?

Comment: I don't think this question is on-topic here. This is a site for Android *users* as opposed to Android developers. [See the faq](http://android.stackexchange.com/faq) for details what questions are considered on-topic here. You might have better luck on Stack Overflow, and in that case a mod can help you with migrating it.

Comment: Sounds like a question about Android architecture and drivers, rather than programming, so I'm pretty sure it is on-topic here. Whether there's anyone that knows Android at a low enough level to be able to answer is a different question, I know I don't know the answer.

Comment: Isn't the nouveau driver specifically for Xorg, which isn't/can't used for Android?

Comment: I agree with @GAThrawn. It's not a _great_ fit, but it's not explicitly off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

Noveau is a driver for the X.org graphics system so it definitely couldn't be used verbatim. The one part that I'd expect to possibly be useful would be the code that actually talks to the hardware. The same is true for any other X.org driver.

But in Noveau's case, most of the work is in reverse-engineering the hardware interface as Nvidia refuses to release the documentation. This work could definitely be reused in a hypothetical Android Nvidia driver.

Answer (score 0):

Almost none of the regular Linux graphics architecture is used on Android (that is, Mesa, XWindows, etc). Driver developers can choose to reuse major portions of their drivers, but there is a lot of plumbing involved to get drivers to work with SurfaceFlinger (and gralloc, and the Hardware Composer), including 3D rendering as well as display output (HDMI support, etc.).